# Python: how to read files

Tags: python

Whenever I try to read a csv file, I get this message!

```
import pandas as pd
read = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Devika\Desktop\New.csv')
  File "<ipython-input-12-15a303f06c16>", line 1
    read = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Devika\Desktop\New.csv')
                  ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Am I making any silly mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
read = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Devika\Desktop\New.csv')
```

or if that doesn't work

```
import os
cfile=os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Devika\Desktop','New.csv')
read = pd.read_csv(cfile)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Both worked!